# Emacs inf-ruby certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby, emacs

I tried to execute an HTTPS request, and it fail in Emacs inf-ruby mode. But it works in bash command line.

```
irb(main):001:0> load ('./get-email-request.rb')
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
    from /home/jyuan/projects/opensources/eloqua-ruby-request/eloqua-ruby-request.rb:52:in `request'
    from /home/jyuan/projects/opensources/eloqua-ruby-request/eloqua-ruby-request.rb:31:in `get'
    from /home/jyuan/projects/opensources/eloqua-ruby-request/examples/get-email-request.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from (irb):9:in `load'
    from (irb):9
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

The ruby configuration is https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/modules/prelude-ruby.el.

Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: It works well after adding https://github.com/senny/rvm.el

Comment: Feel free to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It works well after adding This code. https://github.com/senny/rvm.el